# How to convert dict to list of dict with python

Tags: python

How to convert this dict

```
"Team":{
    "number": '2',
    "persons": ['Doe',"john"]
}
```

to this list of dict

```
"Team" :[
    {"number": '2'},
   { "persons": ['Doe',"john"]}
]
```

I tried the solutions mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621329/how-to-convert-dict-in-list-of-dicts) but nothing works for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be done by list comprehension.

```py
def convert(dictionary):
  return [{key: value} for key, value in dictionary.items()]
```

Then, you get

```py
>>> convert({"number": "2", "persons": ["Doe", "John"]})
[{"number": "2"}, {"persons": ["Doe", "John"]}]
```

Comment: You can even add this : `d["Team"] = [{key: value} for d_values in d.values() for key, value in d_values.items()]` for applying operation on entire dictionary(named as `d`) by OP.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

let's say it's a single dict

```
team_dict = {
    "number": '2',
    "persons": ['Doe',"john"]
}

new_team_dict = [{k: team_dict[k]} for k in team_dict ]
```